# Finding recurrence relation that do not contain GOAL

Tags: recurrence-relations

Find a recurrence relation and initial conditions for $c_n$, the number of sequences of length
$n$ of upper case letters that do not contain GOAL.

Comment: Initial conditions would be
$c_1 = 26, c_2 = 26^2, c_3 = 26^3$, as we can't have GOAL using only first three elements of the sequence. When we go further, things get more complicated. When we try to deduce $c_n$, we have $c_{n-4}$ sequences of length $(n-1)$ that end with GOA. What to do next, I don't yet know, but maybe that would help.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with $a_n$ as the number of sequences of length $n$ that DO contain GOAL. At the same time let us define $b_n$ as the number of sequences of length $n$ ending with GOA and NOT containing an instance of GOAL prior to that. Also let us assume that we have 26 letters.

Then $b_3=a_4=1$ and $b_n=26^{n-3}-a_{n-3}=c_{n-3}$ and then we have
$$
a_{n+1}=a_n+b_n=a_n+c_{n-3}$$
Or put differently $a_{n+1}-a_n=c_{n-3}$. Now we can use this to describe $c_n=26^n-a_n$ where $26^n$ is the total number of possible sequences of length $n$. So
$$
\begin{align}
c_{n+1}-c_n&=26^{n+1}-a_{n+1}-(26^n-a_n)\\
&=26^{n+1}-26^n-(a_{n+1}-a_n)\\
&=26^{n+1}-26^n-c_{n-3}
\end{align}
$$
It now follows that
$$
c_{n+1}=c_n+26^{n+1}-26^n-c_{n-3}
$$
where $c_4=26^4-a_4=26^4-1$. Also $c_1$ and $c_2=26^2$ and $c_3=26^3$.